# Using Cardinality but trying to find total length with it

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I have been using cardinality to find some unique fields, such as author

```
    "aggs": {
       "author_count" : {
        "cardinality" : {
            "field" : "author"
        }
       }
   }
```

This works and counts all the author fields that have a unique author in it.

Now I want to find the total size of these unique authors. With other queries I have just done this by just adding

```
  "aggs":{
    "sum":{
      "field" : "length" }}}
```

But when I have tried this it give me the total length of everything not just for the unique authors.

So for example if the field author contains only one "Kim" this should be returned.
I want every author who has written only single book and add all of their page lengths together too.

e.g

```
"author" : "kim",
"length": 100

"author" : "lolo",
"length": 100
```

The output should be `author_count 2` and `total_length 200`.

But for

```
"author" : "kim",
"length": 100

"author" : "lolo",
"length": 100

"author" : "lolo",
"length": 100
```

The output should be `author_count 1` and `total_length 100`. Because kim is the **only** unique author(author who has written only one book)

Any ideas?

Comment: could you add mapping to the question? why are you getting "lolo" twice?

Comment: because the author lolo may have wrote more than one book

Comment: i meant kim is the only unique author, mappings like author, book, length, dateCreated. stuff like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After understanding the question, this can be achieved with [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) and [sum bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html). First terms aggregation on author field will give all the unique authors, then [value count aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) will give books these unique authors have written.
*total_sum* sums the length of pages.

Now bucket selector will only retain buckets of those authors which have written only single book and finally *sum_bucket* sums all the length of those authors

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_author": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_book_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "author"
          }
        },
        "total_sum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "length"
          }
        },
        "only_single_book_author": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "total_books": "total_book_count"
            },
            "script": "total_books==1"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "page_length": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "unique_author>total_sum"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately, it doesn't include how to add the lengths together, it just give this

Comment: {
               "key": "kim",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "lolo",
               "doc_count": 1

Comment: I am not sure If I understood, could you add sample output to the question? when you say "add lengths together" that would be all documents? or some documents do not have author field?

Comment: I have updated the question, hope this helps. I would like add the lengths of the unique authors together. Hope this makes sense but let me know if it doesn't. Thanks

Comment: I got confused by "length", I think length is another field and I have edited my answer according to that. let me know if this does not work

Comment: This brings back this "aggregations": {
      "unique_author": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "lolo",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "total_length_count": {
                  "value": 200
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "kim",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "total_length_count": {
                  "value": 100
               }

Comment: I think I understood the question, should the output be author_count 1 and total_length 100? Are you trying to get back author who has only written one book? am i right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125854/discussion-between-nicola-and-chintanshah25).